# Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'

Tags: php

I have defined two variables as follows:

```
$pic = get_tax_meta($books->term_id,'books_field_id', true);
$imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $pic[id], 'list-thumb' );
```

`print_r($pic)` results in the following:

```
Array ( [id] => 302 [src] => http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/apic.jpg )
```

However, I get the following warning from $pic[id]:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have fixed the problem:

```
$pic = get_tax_meta($books->term_id,'books_field_id', true);
if (isset($pic['id'])) {
      $picid = $pic['id'];
};
$imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $picid, 'list-thumb' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the array key in quotes like the following.So This

```
$pic[id]
```

Must be

```
$pic['id']
```

Or

```
$pic["id"]
```

Comment: I still get the same warning with or without quotes (single or double)

Comment: Does the Key Actually exist?

Comment: It does for some, for others (if a picture hasn't been uploaded) it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `id` in either single or double quotes:

```
$pic["id"]
```

Or:

```
$pic['id']
```

See [*Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) for more detail.

Comment: I still get the same warning with or without quotes

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $pic[id], 'list-thumb' );
```

with

```
 $imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $pic["id"], 'list-thumb' );
```

Comment: I still get the same warning with or without quotes